# Ignore Pulses Less than a Given Width in a Pulse Train

Tags: filter, pulse, logic-level

Let's say I have a 5V pulse train that varies between 0 and 75000 pulses per second. Pulse width, let's say, is 5 microseconds. How could I calculate or determine the best way to filter out all pulses less than 4 microseconds in width?

Comment: Do you have a clock available?  You could use a counter that counts the number of fast clock cycles for each pulse. A 10 MHz clock could get around 200 ns resolution. Then you could use that signal to only allow long enough pulses through, gating a delayed version of the pulse train. Do you have an FPGA or microcontroller in your system already?

Answer (score 4):

This circuit should do what you want:

[image]

When a pulse comes in on the lead marked IN, it starts the first 74221 monostable (there are two in the same package) which is set for 4 µs.  The output of the monostable \$\small \overline{\text{Q}}\$ pin will be 1 until it is started, then it goes to 0.  So during the 4 µs period, the AND gate (74HCT11) is inhibited so there is no output.  After 4 µs, the AND gate is enabled again, so the rest of the pulse (if longer than 4 µs) goes through to OUT.  See the timing diagrams below.

Since 4 µs has been cut off the beginning of any valid pulse, the second monostable is started on the falling edge of the input pulse (but only if it is longer than 4 µs), and the output remains high to add an additional 4 µs to the end of the output using the OR gate (74HCT32).   Thanks to stefandz for pointing out the need for this additional functionality.

[image]

The buffer marked DS1100Z at the bottom is actually a delay line with a delay of 100 ns; this is to compensate for the propagation delay in the 74123 from trigger to output.

Note because of the tolerance of the capacitor, this timing could be off by 10%, so the resistor should be tweaked as necessary.

*By using monostables, it is trivially easy to modify the timing value from 4 µs to something else just by changing a the resistors and/or capacitors.*

Power pins (Vdd and Vss) and decoupling caps are not shown.

I was originally going to use a 555 timer, but it turns out the 555 is not supposed to be used for pulse widths less than *about* 10 µs.  So I turned to the 74221, which can generate pulses down to the ns range.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this also trims 4us off all pulse lengths which may be of consequence.

Comment: @stefandz I realize that; I don't know any other way to handle that, because you need to look at the pulse for 4 µs before deciding whether to throw it away or not.  If you started to pass all pulses through immediately, and one turned out to be less than 4 µs, you've defeated the purpose of the circuit.

Comment: it's not necessarily an issue - but I would put it in the answer to make it clear to the asker. There is a way around this - in a circuit with memory, such as that by supercat you simply inspect and delay, thus preserving pulse lengths, but introducing a delay to the pulse train.

Comment: @stefandz Since the 74123 is a dual timer, I should be able to add a 4 µs delay at the end of the pulse, to compensate for the 4 µs lost at the beginning.  Back to work.

Comment: now that would be a very neat answer, as it is lower in component count and doesn't have any sampling artefacts :)

Comment: @stefandz: A potential issue with the analog approach is that there will very likely be certain lengths of input pulse which will cause a runt pulse or other such oddity to appear on the output.  A clocked digital signal can reduce such probabilities to essentially zero using a double or triple synchronizer (since the output of reg2 in my circuit is a factor in exactly one synchronous signal, its behavior is equivalent to a triple synchronizer).  Predicting worst-realistic-case behavior for an analog circuit may be much harder.

Comment: @supercat As far as I know, I've eliminated that case by adding the delay line.  It is currently set to 100 ns but can be increased in 100 ns steps.  If you can come up with a specific case where this approach fails, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: On the 74LS123, looking at the data sheet if /A goes low while /Clr is low, nothing will happen.  If /A goes low while /Clr is high, it will output a 4us pulse.  What happens if /A goes low at essentially the same time as /Clr is going low?

Comment: @supercat If the input is exactly 4us, it doesn't matter as long as there is not glitch on the output.  Because there is no delay line going into A of the second monostable, this should prevent that from happening.  In the case where the input is exactly 4us, the second monostable will trigger before the first one times out (by 100 ns or so).

Comment: @tcrosley: An input pulse of suitable length could cause A and /Clr to switch arbitrarily close to each other, and the device data sheet does not specify behavior in that case.  While I've not used the 74LS123 in particular, such devices generally cannot guarantee that there is no possible incoming timing relationship which would not guarantee that an input couldn't be too long to prevent any pulse from being generated, but too short to cause the 74LS123 to switch fully and thus generate a full-length pulse.

Comment: @supercat *I said before*, this could happen only when the input pulse is very close to 4us, and then *it doesn't matter whether it triggers or not*.

Comment: @tcrosley: Cleanly triggering or cleanly deciding not to trigger may both be acceptable, but that doesn't mean runt pulses on the output will be acceptable.  If, for example, the output of the circuit is driving a synchronous counter, an input pulse which is right on the threshold of being detected could cause an 8-bit counter to jump directly from 0x7F or 0xFF to any other value by causing some of the bits to flip while others fail to do so.

Comment: @supercat I redrew my timing diagram for the edge case (4us input pulse) with a resolution of 25 ns (shortest propagation delay).  In one case, I did discover the possibility of an unwanted 25 ns pulse on the output, which as you say could rain havoc.  Fixed it with a third input to the AND gate.  Didn't see anything else.  Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26952/discussion-between-supercat-and-tcrosley).

Comment: [didn't mean to hit "chat"] Metastability is a nasty problem which was surprisingly poorly understood even into the 1980s.  Adding an extra input to the AND gate might help in simulation, but it won't totally fix the problem in real life.  Such changes may change *which* length of input pulse will cause runt pulses on the output, but there's practically no way to avoid the possibility that *some* length of input pulse will cause a runt pulse on the output.  A double synchronizer...

Comment: ...comes very close to eliminating the problem because while it's possible that input timing might cause the latch's output to drop an "almost-latched" signal precisely as the next clock arrives, the timing window where that could occur is extremely small.  Triple synchronization reduces the odds even further since the problematic output from the first latch can't wreak havoc unless it switches at the precise moment required to make the output from the second latch hit just as the third clock pulse arrives.

Comment: @supercat I'm going to disagree with you because of my time delay line.  You have your opinion, I have mine.  I've been designing logic circuits for 55 years.  Let's leave it at that.

Comment: How much have you read about metastability?  If there is some minimum length of input pulse which will cause the overall circuit to generate an output of 100ns or more, and a maximum length which will not generate any output, what will happen if an input pulse is received whose duration is between those?

Comment: @supercat The circuit is all combinatorial except for the 74123's which have FF's. Your earlier concern seemed to be what happens if A goes low at the same time that CLR goes low. The FF will reset within one propagation delay no matter what. There is no possibility of a metastable state or runt pulse.   The circuit will also handle (and reject) arbitrarily small input pulses (e.g. < 10 ns).

Comment: @tcrosley: Gate propagation delays are measured from the time the input reaches a valid level.  If a latching circuit receives a pulse which is long enough to switch the output away from a valid logic level, but not long enough to switch it to a new logic level, there is *no upper limit* on how long the latch may take before it either switches to a new state or reverts to the old one.  Assuming some random distribution of input stimuli, the probability of the output failing to stabilize within a certain time *t* will decrease exponentially with respect to *t*, and...

Comment: ...may reach an acceptably low level within an acceptable time frame, but I don't see anything in the 74LS123 data sheet that would allow one to determine whether the risk of a runt pulse would be one in a million or one in a quadrillion.

Answer (score 2):

In many cases, the simplest approach is to use a synchronous logic circuit which samples the incoming signal at some rate (e.g. 10MHz), ensures that it's synchronized to that clock (passing it through a couple flip flops is a typical way to do this), and then applies whatever logic is needed in purely-digital fashion.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flcd2n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The middle box in the circuit above is a six-bit synchronous-reset counter; every clock pulse will either reset it to zero (if RS is low) or advance the count (if high).

As shown, the circuit will reset the counter on each cycle where the out matches the synchronized value of the input, or increment the counter if they don't match.  If there are 48 consecutive cycles where they don't match, the Q4 and Q5 of the counter will both be high.  On the next cycle, the counter will be reset (regardless of what the input does) and the output will change state.

If the clock is 10Mhz, This circuit will filter out both high and low pulses shorter than roughly 4.9us, and will round all pulse timings to the nearest 100ns.  There are many ways to vary the circuit to implement various kinds of filtering, but the key point is that the input is synchronized to a 10MHz clock and everything else in the circuit runs off the same clock.

Comment: I presume you didn't intend to connect Q and !Q together in your schematic ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to put this in a comment but cannot.

Since no error spec was given, is it possible, to switch from a time domain problem to a voltage again, by integrating the pulses and using a comparator...?

The 0-75kHz range is inconsequential I think and we only need care about the pulse width, ~4us.  If the OP can get a reasonably linear rising edge this might work...?

Cheers