# Pulse width discrimination and measurement

Tags: power-measurement

I need to measure the time period between points A and B of this signal.

[image: Scope trace]

The trace is 5 volts/div and 1 sec/div.  There are 20 to 50 seconds of 
"noise" from point B ta A.  The time between A and B varies from 3 seconds to 15 seconds.

I could use the circuit shown in [EEstackexchange/ignore-pulses-less-than-a-given-width-in-a-pulse-train](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/185387/ignore-pulses-less-than-a-given-width-in-a-pulse-train) to eliminate the very short pulses from B to A, invert that signal and use another discriminator to eliminate the 1 second pulses from A to B, but that's a lot of circuitry.

Is there a simpler way to process this signal?

Comment: A state machine implemented on a micro controller is what springs to mind. Is the 'signature' of the A event 1 second high followed by 1 second low? Is B a high-going event followed by 1 second high? Are those 1 second marker pulses? What happens if B goes high during a marker? Once you've nailed down how to spot each event, you can build a state machine to parse what's happening.

Comment: Have you measured the form of this signal after filter it by a low-pass filter?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your suggestion.  I eventually got this to work on an RPi.  I had to send the signal to two GPIO pins.  The was set up to handle interrupts on the falling edge.  The second was setup up the handle interrupts on the rising edge.