# Can I use a 555 to ignore short DC pulses in simple switch circuit? Not same as usual debouncing

Tags: filter, timer, 555, pulse

I have a reversing camera in my car that I wish to:

- switch on whenever the reverse lights come on
- turn off when reverse lights go off.

Problem is, my car's computer will periodically send these short (let's say 100 ms) 12V pulses to the reverse lights to test whether they are present (simple resistance test).  These pulses are too short to light up the bulbs, but they are short enough to switch on an electronic circuit.

Q. Can I use a 555 timer to ignore those short pulses?  I know I can probably do it with a RC setup, and I realise that I'll end up have resistors and capacitors around the 555 circuit. A delay in switching on the reverse camera is OK.

Cheers!

Comment: Yes. I don't know if you'll even need the 555.

Comment: 0.1s seems long enough to turn on light bulbs. But if not, have you thought of using a relay?

Comment: Yeah I have used a relay previously, I'm exploring if I can use 555 now.

Comment: What type of signal does your reverse camera require in terms of voltage and current? You would really need to state that so we can determine if 555 or other circuit is better.

Comment: @VincePatron turn on is very low - just pulling down a signal line to earth, V+ and GND lines are separate, I don't need to switch those.  Have used a BC547 for that pulling that signal line to previously.

Comment: seems like you want some sort of low pass filter.

Comment: @Jasen ok, cool.  Can you point me in right direction?

Comment: @AndrewMorton haha - yes I do mean that, whoops!  Cheers mate.

Comment: @Chalky Have you seen [Ignore Pulses Less than a Given Width in a Pulse Train](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/185406/36731)? You just need a voltage regulator suitable for an automotive environment, two 555s in monostable mode and logic gates that are happy at whatever voltage you run the circuit at.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, thanks that's exactly what I'm looking for.  If you care to add this as an answer I will accept it.  Cheers!  Yep I can swap his 74221 for 555.  I can also simplify further by dropping the logic he's included on trailing edge of input pulse.

Comment: @AndrewMorton yeah that sounds ideal.  Will do if I can.

Answer (score 0):

use a low-pass filter like this to shield your circuit from the sense pulses.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1khIW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to do this with a timer IC like the 555?

Comment: sure, but you'll still need a resistor and a capacitor.

Comment: Yeah but my question is about what the 555 can do.  Appreciate you answering though, cheers.  It all helps.